# What leads to the existence of critical temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, phase-diagram

We know that $T_c$ is the temperature above which no amount of pressure could force a gas to liquefy.

But why is this? Somehow I don't buy the point that the gas molecules exert too much pressure back to get close and turn into a liquid. If we had tens of thousands of atmosphere pressure (such as on the inside of hot planets), we should be able to liquefy any gas at any temperature.

Comment: This is analogous to other abstractions in physics. For example, at high enough energies, the electro-magnetic force becomes indistinguishable from the weak force. It's just our abstractions failing us, not reality - when you go above "critical temperature / pressure", neither "liquid" nor "gas" adequately describes the "stuff" you're dealing with, and you have a supercritical fluid instead - just like EM+W "becomes" a single combined electroweak force, which behaves in its own way. But again, it's just our models - the simplifications are what breaks down, not reality.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19815/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your description of critical temperature isn't quite right.

If you increase the temperature of a liquid beyond the critical point, the atoms are moving so quickly that persistent structure fails to form and so you have something that behaves a lot like a very dense gas.

Similarly, if you increase the pressure of a gas beyond the critical point, it becomes very dense so that it's like a liquid but without persistent structure.

In other words, it's not so much that the liquid phase does not form, but rather *the liquid and gas phases become indistinguishable* (rather intuitively) and you end up with what's called a [supercritical fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid).

Here's the phase diagram of CO$_2$ for clarity:

[image]

Comment: `In other words, the liquid and gas phase become indistinguishable (rather intuitively) and you end up with what's called a supercritical fluid.` Like deep in Jupiter's atmosphere?

Comment: @cst1992 Yes, and also Venus.

Comment: @cst1992 or at your neighborhood dry cleaners.

Comment: What do you mean by a **persistent structure**?

Comment: @OsheenSachdev liquid molecules stick together to form slightly rigid structures - not dissimilar to a crystal. The difference is that the molecules that form these structures will frequently break away (typically on the pico- to nano-second timescale) and move to some other position. You can partially observe this structure experimentally by measuring the radial distribution function, or study it computationally using molecular simulation.